# Print using join after adding value on the fly

Tags: python, join, printing

I have the following data

```
r = ('P','A','A','P')
newval = 'Q'
newval2 = 'Z'
```

What I want to do is to print the value of `r` together with newval.
But why this failed:

```
   print ",".join([r[0:4],newval,newval2])
```

The desired output is:

```
P,A,A,P,Q,Z
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I would concatenate them as two lists:

```
>>> print ",".join(list(r) + [newval, newval2])
P,A,A,P,Q,Z
```

Answer (score 1):

`r` is of type tuple and [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) accepts only a single level iterable. So, you can concatenate the other data as tuples, like this

```
r, newval, newval2 = ('P','A','A','P'), 'Q', 'Z'
print ",".join(r + (newval,) + (newval2,))
# P,A,A,P,Q,Z
```

Alternatively, you can use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), like this

```
r, newval, newval2 = ('P','A','A','P'), 'Q', 'Z'
from itertools import chain
print ",".join(chain(r, newval, newval2))
```